# Error setting up project with latest version of jQuery Mobile and MDS AppLaud for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova, applaud

I am starting with PhoneGap development. I had set up Eclipse-ADT bundle and MDS AppLaud plugin. When creating a new PhoneGap project, I can chose built-in versions of PhoneGap (1.4.1 to 1.9) and jQuery Mobile 1.1. There's an option to use already installed versions for each one. No problem whith PhoneGap 3.4, but with jQuery, I have this error:

> All .js and .css files in the jQuery Mobile directory
>   /foo/bar/jquery.mobile-1.4.2 must have the same version number of the
>   form jquery.mobile-{version}.*

I removed Demos directory and min versions of css and js, but I still get the same error, maybe because there are some more css files with the form *jquery.mobile.something-1.4.2.css*

How can I solve this error using latest jQuery Mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I delete everything without /images/ folder and these: jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css, jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css, jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js, jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js and everything works great with Eclipse. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally gave up (this question is older than one year) and started using NetBeans where everything works great without big configuration